# How to redcude SQL queries in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I am working on a project where I used eager loading and I want to reduce SQL queries

**ScreenShot1**

[image]

**ScreenShot2**

[image]

```
public function showAllOrdersbySite($domain_id){
    $orders = Order::whereHas('paymentStatus', function ($query) use($domain_id) {
        $query->where("domain_id","=",$domain_id);

    })->orderby('tbl_orders.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return View('admin.all_orders')
            ->with('orders',$orders);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravel Eager loading or Laravel LAzy Eager Loading. Laravel LAzy eager loading fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 0):

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5104

https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=95-best-practice-to-minimize-db-queries/0

[laravel eager loading to minimize queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879347/laravel-eager-loading-to-minimize-queries)

this links may be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

i didn't know that to add with function too i just solve my problem with adding with method like this
source: [Eager Load Constraints Filter issue in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266086/eager-load-constraints-filter-issue-in-laravel)

```
public function showAllOrdersbySite($domain_id){
    $orders = Order::with('func1',func2)->whereHas('paymentStatus', function ($query) use($domain_id) {
        $query->where("domain_id","=",$domain_id);

    })->orderby('tbl_orders.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return View('admin.all_orders')
            ->with('orders',$orders);
}
```